# Maintaining tab order when controls are disabled and enabled again at unpredictable times

Tags: c#, wpf

So let me warn you; I am asking for a way to make a total hack work somewhat better.  I admit that it is a hack and am certainly open to different takes on the problem as a whole.  That said, I need to get this in soon if I want to make code cutoff and we have a somewhat aggressive release date.

As such, I will not be able to make large changes immediately, but I can easily do so for the first patch to this software.  So, short and long term solutions are welcome, but a short term solution (if possible) is preferable.

Ok, so here is the issue; I have an application that send commands to a robotic hardware device.  After a command is sent that requires a wait (for example, a physical motion that takes an unknown amount of time) the UI goes into a "Busy State".  When this occurs all controls that would issue another blocking command are disabled as the machine cannot process them.

When the UI comes out of a busy state all controls are once again enabled, but the tab order is not maintained for obvious reasons.  This makes tabbing through input areas impossible and, seeing as I myself use the keyboard almost exclusively, is not acceptable.  My current scheme to "solve" this problem is to:

1. At startup, register to the GotFocus event for each control of interest in the application.  This is made difficult due to the fact that this is a WPF MVVM app and also because some controls are created dynamically.  Nevertheless, I can search the visual and/or logical trees and get by...
2. In the GotFocus event, save a reference to the control.
3. When we exit a busy state, attempt to set focus to the saved control.

This works... kinda sorta.  The issue at hand (as I can think of more fail scenarios...) is that this logic will blow away a context menu if it was open and another.  Consider:

1. Focus is in a text area.
2. User right clicks another control.  This control does *not* get focus (even if I try to set it in a mouse handler).
3. System goes into a busy state as the right click performed a move.
4. When the busy state ends, text area is given focus and the context menu closes.

(Now I realize that you may say that performing a move on a right click and also displaying a context menu is a bad idea, but the context menu commands are non-blocking, enabled, and it has a domain specific use that is convenient.)

So there it is. I can't even get focus in a right click, and setting focus to the menu itself doesn't work either.  I'm just curious if anyone has a better scheme for something like this. I realize it is awkward and a very narrow circumstance.  Thanks for any help you can offer in advance, I will be playing around with this some more...

Answer (score 10):

Interesting question and sadly i cannot think of an immediate solution to the problem, i would try to work around the issue by not blocking the application at all if this is such a frequent thing.

If the roboter can only take one command at a time it might work to just implement a command-queue so that the interface can still be used and while the roboter is busy issued commands get deferred. In terms of usability it might be a good idea to make this queue very visible so it is apparent that the command has been issued and will be taken into account.

Comment: Yeah, this is a good idea.  We do currently queue up commands to be sent to the machine, but we only use a priority scheme to determine when to send them (i.e., they get sent in order, but do not normally take busy state into consideration).  We could be smarter on the client side and not send commands until the busy state is over, thus removing the need for disabling controls.  The only problem is that this is a long term goal (and one I will start working on), but we are in the verification phase right now, so no time for this release.  +1 for a good suggestion.

Comment: And BTW, like I said before, there may not be a good workaround currently, so my question may not have an answer at all in the short term.

Answer (score 3):

How about instead of actually disabling controls you just do a check when they are invoked if they should send the command or not in the beginning of their event handlers. eg:

```
if(!bControlsEnabled) { return; }
```

You could also change the controls style when they should be "disabled".

Comment: Yes, in the future I would like to simply get rid of disabling them completely, but this is actually a clever workaround; don't disable them at all, just make them appear to be disabled and disable the command(s).  This unfortunately would be too much work for now (we entered VER yesterday and need to complete it by next week, so I don't think management would approve this), but I like it. +1

Comment: I don't think there is a perfect solution, and this one is addresses the issue at hand in the least hackish way possible while not being overly burdensome.  Like I said, it may be too late to implement at this point, but hey, you still deserve the bounty. ;)

Comment: @Ed, actually this is the best short-term solution. Just wrap it in attached behavior and you are good to go. What's the amount of control controls? What are they?

Comment: @Anvaka: Which is why I gave it the bounty :).  It meets my criteria, it's just that we are regulated by the FDA and have pretty strict controls in place.  As we have now transitioned into the verification phase code checkins are only allowed if in response to a bug.  Management has deemed this bug acceptable to leave unfixed for VER and will allow me to fix it in a future version, by which time I would like to modify the message pump architecture to make the entire thing irrelevant.  BTW, there are a lot of controls, pretty much every control in the app would need modification to some degree.

Comment: Got it. After I posted my comment I realized that you already accepted the answer. Good luck with the fix :)!

Answer (score 1):

Implement a custom behavior that listens when your control's enabled changes, saves the focused element and refocuses that element when enabled changes back to true:

```
public class KeyboardFocus
{
    public static bool GetReturnFocusAfterEnable(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (bool)obj.GetValue(ReturnFocusAfterEnableProperty);
    }

    public static void SetReturnFocusAfterEnable(DependencyObject obj, bool value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(ReturnFocusAfterEnableProperty, value);
    }

    private static Dictionary<object, IInputElement> values = new Dictionary<object, IInputElement>();

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for ReturnFocusAfterEnable.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ReturnFocusAfterEnableProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("ReturnFocusAfterEnable", typeof(bool), typeof(KeyboardFocus), new UIPropertyMetadata(false, PropertyChangedCallback));

    static void PropertyChangedCallback(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if ((bool)e.NewValue)
        {
            UIElement element = d as UIElement;
            if (element != null)
            {
                element.IsEnabledChanged += (element_IsEnabledChanged);
            }

        }
        else
        {
            UIElement element = d as UIElement;
            if (element != null)
            {
                element.IsEnabledChanged -= (element_IsEnabledChanged);
            }

        }
    }

    static void element_IsEnabledChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if ((bool)e.NewValue)
        {
            if (values.ContainsKey(sender))
            {
                Keyboard.Focus(values[sender]);
                values.Remove(sender);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            values[sender] = Keyboard.FocusedElement;
        }            
    }
}
```

This could then be implemented in XAML as such:

```
<Grid Name="layout" local:KeyboardFocus.ReturnFocusAfterEnable="True">
```

This works in my test setup, but if you press a button before disabling your stuff, that button would have keyboard focus at the time the thing gets disabled, and this fails.

This solution is independant of your architecture, and does not require code in the form. It's a bit quick and dirty but it does the job.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Unfortunately this seems to exhibit the same problem as my original solution regarding context menus.  For the life of me I can seem to figure out how context menus fit into this...

Answer (score 1):

Workaround for this :-Instead of disabling the control You should use XamBusyIndicator as a parent of that control and set the property for IsBusy. If IsBusy is true it will disable the child control and also TabIndex property will run in a sensible manner.
For example:-

```
<igComboEditor:XamBusyIndicator IsBusy="{Binding IsBusy}" Height="22">
                                <igComboEditor:XamBusyIndicator.Animation>
                                    <igComboEditor:CustomBusyAnimation DataTemplate="{StaticResource CustomBusyIndicatorTemplate}" />
                                </igComboEditor:XamBusyIndicator.Animation>
                                <igComboEditor:XamComboEditor Width="125"  VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Style="{StaticResource XamComboEditorStyle}"
                                                          ItemsSource="{Binding DataList}" IsEditable="False" 
                                                          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedData}">

                            </igComboEditor:XamComboEditor>
                            </igComboEditor:XamBusyIndicator>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would

```
OnCommandSentThatRequiresAWait Event Call SaveStateAndDisableUI()

SaveStateAndDisableUI()
{
   Foreach control in controlsCollection
   {
       switch(controlType)
       {
           for each control extract and save all you need. 
           if it's a menu check if it is opened up and so on, 
           does control have focus, 
           where is the caret located in case of textbox etc              
       }
   }
   save position of mouse x,y
   save position of form, state like if it is minimized, maximized
}

Corresponding RestoreState() should restore everything back up.
```